# Can an alternator recharge a battery in an EV

Tags: batteries, alternator

Can you recharge a EV's electric battery with an alternator hooked up to the axle of the EV?
This question came from a conversation with my Grandpa, and I was looking for an explanation for him of why it could work/not work.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, EV's already have alternators. An alternator is just a generator that uses magnets and coils of wire to generate electricity from the rotational energy of the wheels. EV's don't need a discrete alternator because the wheels are already attached to the electric motor, which can act as a generator when performing regenerative braking/coasting.

So in a sense, the answer to your question is that this is already done, except that they use the electric motor instead of a discrete alternator.

However, there is an important difference in the way that alternators in gasoline cars and electric motors in EVs are used to generate electricity. In a gasoline car, the alternator is always running, as this is the primary method by which the 12v (low voltage) battery is kept charged.

In contrast, in an EV, the high voltage battery (typically 200V+) has ample capacity to keep the low-voltage system up and running for the full range the battery can provide. So the electric motor is only really used as an alternator when you are braking or coasting, then using the kinetic energy of the moving vehicle to charge the batteries and get some range back. There would be little point to doing this while accelerating (think about conservation of energy + efficiency losses in converting from electrical energy to mechanical energy and back again...)

There are some small caveats here, since some hybrids will actually use the gasoline engine to charge the high voltage batteries when they get low. But in general, alternators in traditional gasoline cars are always producing energy (and consuming gasoline to do it) whereas EV motors are only used as generators when braking or coasting.

Answer (score 0):

[TANSTAAFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch). In brief, the amount of energy returned by the alternator is never 100% of that put into forcing it to turn.

That said, electric vehicles ascending and then descending hills, or making frequent stops, *do* recharge their batteries somewhat (almost all electric vehicles have [regenerative braking](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/auto-parts/brakes/brake-types/regenerative-braking.htm), where the motor operates as a generator to slow the car and recharge the battery). Though this recovers less than  100% of the energy, it's still far better than wasting all the energy of braking as heat in the brakes, as do combustion-powered vehicles.

An extreme case: a [mining vehicle that *never* needs to be recharged](https://www.autoblog.com/2019/08/26/edumper-electric-mining-truck-self-charging/) has been made! That is only possible because it carries heavy loads from the top of a quarry to the base, fully charging the battery, and returns to the top *empty*, far lighter and requiring less energy to ascend. So, TANSTAAFL still applies.

Perhaps you might explore thermodynamics. [According to Allan Ginsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginsberg%27s_theorem), "You can't win, you can't break even, and you can't even get out of the game."

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, you don't actually need an *alternator* to do this, as many current EVs already generate power when slowing down (regenerative braking) or coasting. The good news is that you can significantly cut down on total energy usage by doing this. In a regular ICE car, all the energy from braking is lost as heat. In an EV, some of that energy gets turned back into electricity so you can use it later. Note that not all EV braking works that way - sometimes you just need to stop quickly and traditional brakes, turning motion into heat, are still used.

In fact, it is possible to tow an EV - or drive it downhill - and end up with more energy in the battery at the end of the trip than at the start of the trip, though that energy is coming from another vehicle (which will have used more energy than it would have if it were not towing your EV) or from gravity.

However, there are limits. There will always be *some* energy turned into heat or used to actually get your car from point A to point B. If you could recover *all* the energy as electricity then you would have a perpetual motion machine, which simply doesn't exist.